Looking for a plugin that allow customize product/service sell process
I am looking for a plugin that will allow me to sell a configurable service. I have two ideas, I click on a service and go to a page where I choose various options such as making a print on a T-shirt, what size, whether it should be colored, the number of prints, etc. Depending on what options I choose, the price is calculated on the fly for the user. The second idea is something like this process, i.e. I go straight to the page where I choose where I want to place the print, I click next, I go to another page where I choose some other things and on each page the price also changes depending on what the user clicks. It is known that this is just an example, I do not want functionality with uploading photos on a T-shirt. Does anyone know any plugin that should interest me?

Plugin recommendations are off topic for this Stack, see: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

There's dozens of ways to achieve what you want. Your question above is actually like a dozen different questions.  What you're asking for is pricing variables in WooCommerce. You build attributes and then variations of all the attributes in different combinations that impact the price. I don't remember what it's called but there's even a secondary plugin that adjusts product prices. Like this:  https://ribboncanada.com/product/double-face-satin-custom-printed/
